# Change UITextLabel of a UITableViewCell when pressed

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield

i've done a feed reader with a UITableView structure, i would to change the UITextLabel TextColor after an user click on it (like reeader app)

could someone help me?

thank you,
devskip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a built-in table view cell style, all you have to do is set the [highlightedTextColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW4) of the cell's labels. Then, when the cell is highlighted, the labels will change color as appropriate.

If you're using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, you can still set the `highlightedTextColor`, but you must also override `setHighlighted:animated:` to update the [highlighted](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW3) property of any labels.